# Automatically generate nested SCSS from regular CSS?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, postcss

I'd like to take some legacy CSS files and convert them to SCSS with nested styles. For example:

**Input**

```
#SomeElement .button { /*Some styles*/ }

#SomeElement .link { /*Some styles*/ }
```

**Output**

```
#SomeElement {
    .button { /*Some styles*/ }
    .link { /*Some styles*/ }
}
```

Is there any tool to make this project manageable with thousands of lines of CSS to convert? I understand there may be some edge cases that need manual fixing, but it would be great to be able to jump start the process with some sort of automatic conversion.

Would PostCSS or Gulp have any tools I could leverage?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/johno/gulp-css-scss It isn't apparent from the documentation whether it does what you want.  The online app http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/ does what you want but I am not sure you could incorporate its code into a task runner....

Comment: gulp-css-scss looks promising. I'll report back once I've had a chance to give it a try. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? I'm not entirely sure I understand the point of post-processing CSS in order to convert it into a further that requires preprocessing to convert it back to CSS; I'm sure there *is* a reason, I'm just not seeing it...

Comment: The legacy code is very unwieldy, but I need to make some changes to it for a project which will further increase the difficulty of working with the file. Long term, moving to SCSS seems likely to save a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 4):

1. **By using this you can change your css to scss** 
   http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/
2. **Using Gulp**
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-scss